# How download an installed app with nanohttpd

Tags: java, http, nanohttpd

Hello i want to make a http server with nanohttpd that shows installed apps, and convert them to apk and download. I can list but how can i download the app i select

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA;
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

        String name = String.valueOf(packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo));
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            name = packageInfo.packageName;
        }
        Drawable icon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo);
        String apkPath = packageInfo.sourceDir;
        apps.add(new App(name, apkPath, icon, packageInfo.packageName));
}

if (method.equals(Method.GET)) {
    for (App file : apps) {

        answer += "<a href=\"" + file.getAppName()
                + "\" alt = \"\">" + file.getAppName()
                + "</a><br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I basicly take the url after list the apps and check which appname equal to url after that i start to download it like that

```
 if (method.equals(Method.GET)) {
            if (a) {
                answer = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; " +
                        "charset=utf-8\"><title> HTTP File Browser</title>";
                for (App file : appShare) {
                    answer += "<a href=\"" + file.getAppName()
                            + "\" alt = \"\">" + file.getAppName()
                            + "</a><br>";
                }
                answer += "</head></html>";
                if(blabla.equals(header.get("referer"))){
                    a=false;
                }

            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < appShare.size(); i++) {
                    if (appShare.get(i).getAppName().equals(appnames))
                        arrayC = i;
                }
                answer = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; " +
                        "charset=utf-8\"><title> Download " + appShare.get(arrayC).getAppName() + "</title>";
                // serve file download
                InputStream inputStream;
                Response response = null;

                if (mStatusUpdateListener != null) {
                    mStatusUpdateListener.onDownloadingFile(
                            new File(appShare.get(arrayC).getApkPath()), false);
                }

                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(

                            new File(appShare.get(arrayC).getApkPath()));
                    response = new DownloadResponse(

                            new File(appShare.get(arrayC).getApkPath()), inputStream);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }            response.addHeader(
                        "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + appShare.get(arrayC).getAppName()+".apk");
                return response;


            }
```